# 2D Array and a loop within an interval

Tags: java

I need to crate a loop which sums the arrays values which are within the interval (for instance 2-5). My main problem is getting from the first checked value of the array to the next one and so on. Thankyou in advance.

```
int x=0,y=0,s=0;
int[][] myArray = { {0,1,2,3}, {3,2,1,0}, {3,5,6,1}, {3,8,3,4} };  
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
int b = scan.nextInt();//lowest value
int c = scan.nextInt(); //highest value
if (myArray[x][y]>b || myArray[x][y]<c)
    s=s+myArray[x][y]  
//then check next one
```

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: OK, I answered without noticing the "2D" in your title, but now that I've seen it: how does an "interval" of "2-5" define a range in a 2D array? Please click "edit" and add a sample input array, sample interval and corresponding desired output.

Comment: For your edit: you need a nested for loop to handle both dimensions of the array, and your _if_ condition should use && rather than ||.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (myArray[x][y]>b || myArray[x][y]<c)
    s=s+myArray[x][y]
```

You need to put these in a nested for-loop. Otherwise, they are executed only once, with `x=0` and `y=0`. So all you are doing is essentially:

```
if (myArray[0][0]>b || myArray[0][0]<c)
    s=s+myArray[0][0]
```

So `s` could only possibly be `0` or the first element in the 2D array.

Now, this conditional:

```
if (myArray[x][y]>b || myArray[x][y]<c)
```

does not mean what you think it means. This would evaluate to true **for all numbers** as long as `b` is less than `c`. For the semantics you are looking for, you want an `AND` operator (`&&`).